# Как создать обертку на java для python?

Tags: java, python, servlet

Есть система на python, надо, чтобы она запускалась из-под JSP. Мне нужно написать обертку для этой системы, чтобы ее можно было собрать в java-приложение и запустить на кластере.

Я не работал с кластерами. Но знаю python. Есть знание на java, a c сервлетами не знаком.

Можете направить в правильно русло, где что можно почитать или примеры какие то, очень нужно.

Comment: Почитать лучше что-нибудь о проектировании систем, чтобы понять, что не надо так делать. В крайнем случае, если уж пытаетесь спарить тигра с носорогом, запустите программу на python как web-сервис и обращайтесь из java к этому web-сервису.

Comment: Без обертки, это как интересно?

Comment: Понятия не имею, как написана ваша python-программа, но не могу представить ситуации, в которой нельзя вынести основную логику в функции, которые могут вызывать предельно простые обработчики uWSGI или aiohttp.

Comment: Я могу ссылку скинуть на репозиторию, просто очень нужно